# wpf threading, backgroundworker, dispatcher

Tags: wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am new to wpf threading, now that we have backgroundworker and dispatcher classes, classic winforms threading issues are no longer a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have plenty of hands on threading experience in a professional situation, including quite a bit with WPF, and I can tell you that it does not solve any of these problems.

It is nicer than winforms in that the Dispatcher gives you a more clear idea of what the threading model is, but it doesn't go much further than that.

There isn't really much more that it *could* do even if they wanted to. Threading is an inherently complicated and ugly thing, and you can't just magically make it go away with a few GUI libraries

Answer (score 10):

You can still have *all* of these problems. WPF hasn't magically solved any threading issue. It just gives you a couple more tools to use. *BackgroundWorker* has been around for a while, and although useful, it is still just as possible to get deadlocks, race conditions, etc. The best cure for threading issues, is, as always, careful development and careful debugging.

Comment: The fact that he is "a" student (not "just a student") doesn't disqualify him from providing a very valid answer.  I think the comment is uncalled for, please remove it.

Comment: Hahaha I may be "just a student" but I have experience in WPF through my internship. Furthermore, as "just a student" I know that these are problems INHERENT to threading, and cannot be fixed with libraries.

Comment: This answer is correct.  There's not any magic here.  You are still responsible for understanding these concepts and mitigating risks.  If you lock a resource or write to a shared location, you'd best be sure you have your ducks in a row - this goes for any threading model.  Regardless if you are writing your code as a homework assignment or a work assignment ;-)

Comment: @user147456: Being insulting or rude to people trying to help you makes others not want to help you. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) pages, particularly the section on acceptable behavior. Being nice to others gets you more and better help when you need it. Thanks.

Comment: @Ken: While I agree (and I saw the flag, too), the OP hasn't been on SO in nearly two years.